# How do you dynamically expand array and update?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to wrap my head around how the logic works.  The idea is to dynamically allocate memory because I won't know how many iterations the program will go through and I can't use vectors.  So here is an abstraction of what I have so far.  I have a do while loop that contains the variable `count` which will act as the `SIZE` of the array.  `update` is what will be stored in the array.  The thing i can't figure out is how to update the array `iPoint` without making an infinite amount of `if else` statements.  I know there is a better way but at this point my brain is fried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int iTickets, count = 0, update = 0;
    int *tempiPoint = NULL;
    int *iPoint = NULL;

    do
    {
        count++;
        update++;


        if (count == 1)
        {


            tempiPoint = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                *(tempiPoint + i) = update;
            }

        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {


            iPoint = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                *(iPoint + i) = *(tempiPoint + i);

            }
            *(iPoint + count) = update;


        }

    } while (count != 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << *(iPoint + i);
}
    delete[] tempiPoint;
    delete[] iPoint;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  It automatically resizes as necessary.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use vectors?  Is that an academic restriction?

Comment: @Wug yes, we're using arrays even though we did not go through the chapter on arrays.  *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the loop iterates, you need to:

1. Free `tempiPoint`'s memory, as it was dynamically allocated in the previous iteration.
2. Reallocate it with `iPoint`'s current size.
3. Copy `iPoint`'s data into `tempiPoint`.
4. Free `iPoint`'s memory and reallocate it with the new size.
5. Copy `tempiPoint`'s data back into `iPoint` and then add the new value to the end of `iPoint`.

Also, note that `*(iPoint + count)` is equivalent to `iPoint[count]` (and that this is the syntax you should be using).

This appears to be homework so I'm leaving the implementation to you.

A far better  and simpler solution (pointed out in the comments by Ben Voigt) is to simply have `tempiPoint` *point* to `iPoint`'s memory, reallocate `iPoint`, transfer the data back to `iPoint` using `tempiPoint` and then free the memory.

Comment: You can do half as many copies by swapping the pointers.  You can cut the number of copies a lot more by increasing the size by N every Nth iteration.  (vector actually increases by a percentage when the capacity is reached; this is required by Standard language that decrees amortized insertion complexity)

Comment: Your first point is fair and I'll edit it into my answer, but your second point doesn't seem to be relevant to his assignment as it doesn't seem like the emphasis is on efficiency (as opposed to implementing a vector in a data structures course).

Comment: At some level it is useful to make students aware that the library feature does all this grunt work *and a lot more and is tested*, even though you aren't expecting them to replicate the complexity of the library.  Knowing what the library does is useful for using it well; that presumably is the reason for implementing a growing array -- to understand what happens inside the standard library.  But if you never tell the students that the standard library does this better, they make keep using their version even when the "no library" constraint is dropped.

Comment: Fun fact: doubling the size of the allocated vector on reallocations is mathematically a poor choice. Because the sum of powers of two will always be less than the next highest power of two, the reallocated vector storage will never fit in any of its previously used space, and it will always walk forwards in memory. For that reason, it's better to use something like 1.9 as a scale factor.  I read an article about this some time ago, but can't find it right now.